# How to choose groups where there are more than 5 observations

Tags: r

I have dataset with the 3 columns.

```
price
Factor (numeric var 1-15 categories)
group (string (100 categories))
```

I need for each Factor categories select only these groups who have observation more then five! How do it?

This is not correct!

```
new<-city[(city$group)>5,]
```

Comment: Use `?table` to compute the frequency per factor and then subset

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by 'Factor', 'group', get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) where the number of rows is greater than 5 (`.N >5`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(city)[, .SD[.N >5], by = .(Factor, group)]
```